# Unity3D - let gameobject blink with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project I have an **Empty GameObject**  which has 3 child **GameObjects**. The **Empty GameObject** is called `Cable Strip` and if the camera move to a special position, I want that the material of the three child Object start to change from white to yellow and back. Unfortunately all my solutions does not work.

This is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine

public class BlinkingObject : MonoBehaviou
{
    public GameObject CableStrip;
    public Material white, yellow;

    public GameObject camManager; //Empty GameObject with the Main Camera
    private Vector3 camPosition;

    bool blinkObject;

    void Update()
    {
         if(camManager.transform.position == camPosition)
         {
             InvokeRepeating("Blink", 0, 1);
         }
    }

    public void Blink()
    {
       Renderer[] colorCable = CableStrip.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
       foreach (var cableChild in colorCable)
       {
           if(blinkObject)
           {
               cableChild.material = yellow;
               blinkObject = false; 
           } else
           {
               cableChild.material = white;
               blinkObject = true; 
           }
       }
   }
}
```

How can I get my gameobject to blink in a nice way?

### Edit

Sorry wrong definition of *does not work*. The problem is, that the color changes too fast. Even if I change the seconds by `InvokeRepeating` nothing changes. It still changes the color in milliseconds even if I write `InvokeRepeating("Blink", 0, 10);`.

Comment: possibly because you are constantly invoking the blinking..  does it run the blink method? what happens if instead of the changes of materials you put debug messages....

Comment: is this ever `true` : `camManager.transform.position == camPosition` ?

Comment: @BugFinder if i use debug messages it switches between the two messages

Comment: @derHugo not sure, i am new to c# but it works fine in all my c# script .. if you have a better solution i´d love to see it :)

Comment: @diem_L well, if the debug messages work then its doing it, so:  are the debug messages once a second? Id guess it could be once a frame while the camera is in the right position ergo if you get say 200fps, its flipping 200 times a second and you dont see the colour change

Comment: @BugFinder yeah it is once a frame. in fact i see the color change, but it is so fast, that it is hard to see, so for my project it is way too fast.

Comment: so there you go, its doing it every frame.. @derHugo has shown a better way, or, you could alter your code so it can only call that invoking once..... until it leaves that position and returns..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem:

```
InvokeRepeating("Blink", 0, 1);
```

is called multiple times. So every frame the condition is fulfilled you add a new repeating invoke ... ending up with probably thousands of parallel invocations that are always repeating.

---

What you want to do instead is **enabling** the blink when the condition is fulfilled and **disable** it when not. I wouldn't use `Invoke` or `InvokeReapting` in this case. You can achieve it by simply using a timer:

```
private float timer;
private bool blinkObject;

private Renderer[] colorCable;

private void Awake()
{
    // you want to do this only once!
    colorCable = CableStrip.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
}

private void Update()
{
     HandleBlink();
}

// As suggested by Cid you can ofcourse move it all to a method
// so you don't disturb other things happening in Update
private void HandleBlink()
{
     // is the condition fulfilled?
     var doBlink = camManager.transform.position == camPosition;

     // if not do nothing
     if(!doBlink) return;

     // reduce the timer by time passed since last frame
     timer -= Time.deltaTime;

     // if timer not under 0 do nothing else
     if(timer > 0) return;

     // If timer exceeded invert the blinkObject flag
     blinkObject = !blinkObject;

     foreach (var cableChild in colorCable)
     {
         // Shorthand for if(blinkObject) { ... = yellow; } else { ... = white; }
         cableChild.material = blinkObject ? yellow : white;
     }

     // and reset the timer
     timer = 1f;
}
```

---

Alternatively the same thing could also be achieved by using a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which is often a bit cleaner (but that's opinions):

```
// flag for preventing concurrent routines
private bool isBlinking;

private Renderer[] colorCable;

private void Awake()
{
    // you want to do this only once!
    colorCable = CableStrip.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
}

private void Update()
{
     // is the condition fulfilled?
     if(camManager.transform.position == camPosition)
     {
         if(!isBlinking) StartCoroutine(BlinkRoutine());
     }
     else
     {
         StopAllCoroutines();
         isBlinking = false;
     }
}

private IEnumerator BlinkRoutine()
{
     isBlinking = true;

     var blinkObject = false;

     // this looks scary but is fine in a Coroutine
     // as long as you YIELD somewhere inside!
     while(true)
     {
         blinkObject = !blinkObject;

         foreach (var cableChild in colorCable)
         {
             // Shorthand for if(blinkObject) { ... = yellow; } else { ... = white; }
             cableChild.material = blinkObject ? yellow : white;
         }

         yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Definitely the answer I was typing :D However I would move the actual content of `Update` in a specific method, there may be more stuff to do there and one doesn't want to `return;`

Comment: @Cid ... due to single responsibility a class called `BlinkingObject` should do nothing else than make the object blink but sure why not ;)

Comment: Yes, but who knows, sometime a blinking object launches rockets and candies too

Comment: once again @derHugo you are awesome :) thanks for the solution, it works perfect.

Comment: @diem_L glad to be of help ;)